# create a property starting with digit

Tags: c#, .net, class

why cant i create a property in class starting with a digit or special character?

P.S. I'm kinda new to c#

```
public class Test
{
 public int 1property {get;set;}
}
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Because the C# language specifications (specifically, section 2.4.2) state that you cannot.

It also makes things easier for the parser in terms of figuring out whether a given token is a literal number of an identifier.  Identifiers can have numbers in them, they just can't start with a number.  The first letter of any identifier must be a character or the underscore character (`_`).

Answer (score 36):

If you're like me, and you were searching for this because you wanted to deserialize JSON from a third-party API that named properties starting with digits:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
public class ThirdPartyAPIResult
{
    [JsonProperty("24h_volume_usd")]
    public double DailyVolumeUSD { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I'm like you.. Thanks

Comment: Interesting. My problematic property has the same name. :)

Comment: Then just deserialize using this: JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<T>>(string); For multiple JSON objects.

Comment: This was a big help. Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

[Identifier/Property Names cannot ***start with*** integer values.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664670%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) Consider the following alternatives:

```
public class Test
{
     public int PropertyOne {get;set;}
     public int Property1 {get;set;}
     public int Property_1 {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: I also think this is the best answer. Most of the time it's better to suffix the digit/numeric value either spelled out or in numeric form. Also, consider using an ordinal approach, such as `FirstObject`, `SecondObject`. In other cases it may be beneficial to differentiate them based on their origin, such as `SourceObject`, `DestinationObject` or `TargetObject`.

Answer (score 6):

As per C# Identifier rules - Identifiers cannot start with a digit.

So you can not create `variablename`,`classname`,`methodname`,`interfacename` or `propertyname` starting with a digit.

but Identifiers can start with `underscore`.

Try this:

```
public class Test
{
    public int _1property {get;set;}
}
```