# C# names starting with numbers workaround

Tags: c#, .net, enums, numbers, naming

I'm creating an enum for different weapon calibres in c# which usually start with digits, resulting in errors.

```
public enum Caliber
{
    9x19,
    9x18,
    5x56
    //etc
}
```

The code above is obviously not working as .NET doesn't allow variable/class names to start with numbers. Is there any workaround to this issue that I'm not aware of, or do I simply have to append some sort of prefix to every entry?

Comment: Yeah you'll have to use a prefix like underscore.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16008007/using-numbers-at-the-beginning-of-variable-name

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20748774/create-a-property-starting-with-digit

Comment: Are you sure that enum is appropriate data structure for such thing as caliber?

Comment: @GuruStron what else? I'll only have a few predefined types (as seen in the list above), so i see nothing wrong

Comment: Bit more verbose - NineXNineteen, NineXEighteen .....

Comment: @BirgerEvansson of course it depends on your app business logic and in some cases it can be fine, but personally I would consider future when you will need to extend it and/or determine some information from the caliber. Probably something more dynamic then enum can be of use.